# Como corrigir esse e outros erros: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'list'?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Estou implementando um exemplo de um livro sobre `Spring Boot`, mas, depois de executar, ao tentar acessar a rota `/clientes/list` ou, então, `/clientes/view` no navegador aparecem os seguintes erros:

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'com.greendog.modelos.Cliente'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for
>   value 'list'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For
>   input string: "list"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei como resolver.
Seguem meu códigos:

Classe `Cliente.java`:

```
package com.greendog.modelos;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;

import com.greendog.modelos.Pedido;

@Entity
public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Length(min=2, max=30, message="O tamanho do nome deve ser entre {min} e {max} caracteres.")
    private String nome;

    @NotNull
    @Length(min=2, max=300, message="O tamanho do endereçomdeve ser entre {min} e {max} caracteres.")
    private String endereco;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cliente", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Pedido> pedidos;


    public Cliente(Long id, String nome, String endereco) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public void novoPedido(Pedido pedido) {
        if(this.pedidos == null) pedidos = new ArrayList<Pedido>();
        pedidos.add(pedido);

    }
     /*Getter e Setter */
}
```

Interface `ClienteRepository.java`:

```
package com.greendog.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.greendog.modelos.Cliente;

@Repository
public interface ClienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Cliente, Long>{

}
```

Classe `ClienteController.java`:

```
package com.greendog.controladores;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import com.greendog.modelos.Cliente;
import com.greendog.repositories.ClienteRepository;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/clientes")
public class ClienteController {

    @Autowired
    private final ClienteRepository clienteRepository = null;

    //Exibe as lista de Clientes
    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView list() {
        Iterable<Cliente> clientes = this.clienteRepository.findAll();
        return new ModelAndView("clientes/list", "clientes", clientes);
    }

    //Exibe o detalhe de cada cliente
    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public ModelAndView view(@PathVariable("id") Cliente cliente) {
        return new ModelAndView("clientes/view", "cliente", cliente);
    }

    //Direciona para criar novo cliente
    @GetMapping("/novo")
    public String createForm(@ModelAttribute Cliente cliente) {
        return "clientes/form";
    }

    //Insere novo cliente através de um formulario
    @PostMapping(params = "form")
    public ModelAndView create(@Valid Cliente cliente, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirect) {
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return new ModelAndView("clientes/" + "form", "formErros", result.getAllErrors());
        }

        cliente = this.clienteRepository.save(cliente);
        redirect.addFlashAttribute("globalMessage", "Cliente gravado com sucesso!");

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/" + "clientes/" + "{cliente.id}", "cliente.id", cliente.getId());
    }

    //Atualizar cliente
    @GetMapping(value = "alterar/id")
    public ModelAndView alterarForm(@PathVariable("id") Cliente cliente) {
        return new ModelAndView("cliente/form", "cliente", cliente);
    }

    //Remover Cliente
    public ModelAndView remover(@PathVariable("id") Long id, RedirectAttributes redirect) {
        this.clienteRepository.deleteById(id);
        Iterable<Cliente> clientes = this.clienteRepository.findAll();
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("clientes/list","clientes", clientes);
        mv.addObject("globalMessage", "Cliente removido com sucesso!");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Minha estrutura de pastas desse projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código completo no [GitHub](https://github.com/vanribeiro/ExemploDoLivroDeSpringBootFB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ele está caindo nessa exceção porque você está chamando incorretamente o seu endpoint, quando você chama o caminho /clientes/list na verdade você está passando a string "list" pro seu método view, o que causa sua exceção, o certo seria clientes/15 por exemplo, sendo 15 a id do seu cliente, ou apenas clientes para chamar o método list

---

editando aqui a resposta porque percebi que tem vários errinhos vendo seu git
1° Seu métodos dos seus controllers, perceba que você está usando o método ModelAndView passando no construtor o nome da view, o nome da model e em seguida o objeto da model, a sua model se chama cliente e na hora de passar você ta passando clientes no plural em algumas chamadas, precisa ser igual porque senão ele não identifica.
2° seu método view você tá recebendo uma model mas colocou o nome de id, acho que você se confundiu aqui, ao meu ver você deveria trocar esse Cliente por long id
3° ainda no seu método view, você ta passando o cliente sem nada, isso la no front vai dar uma exceção por nulo, alterando seu método ele ficou assim pra mim:

```
@GetMapping("{id}")
    public ModelAndView view(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente(id, "Lucas", "123456"); //essa parte aqui você deve trocar pelo seu select
        return new ModelAndView("view", "cliente", cliente);
    }
```

4° no seu html você colocou na view que está dando erro na linha 10 `th:if="{globalMessage}"`, falta um cifrão aqui e por isso estava dando erro ao parsear, o certo seria `th:if="${globalMessage}"`

Comment: Oi, Lucas! Muito obrigada por responder! Inseri alguns dados nessa tabela para teste e quando tento acessar da forma como me disse recebo essa exceção: `Error resolving template "clientes/view", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers`.

Comment: você está tentando retornar o arquivo view da pasta templates? porque observe a estrutura da sua pasta templates, da forma como está você está sugerindo que lá existe uma pasta chamada clientes e dentro delas e esta seu arquivo view, se for esse o caso você deveria substituir o seu return para  return new ModelAndView("view", "cliente", cliente);

Comment: Ao fazer a alteração que você sugeriu, aparece esse erro `An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/view.html]")`.

Comment: aí agora eu preciso ver como tá a view.html pra entender rsrs

Comment: Sem problemas... rsrs... Caso queira ver o código completo, coloquei no [GitHub](https://github.com/vanribeiro/ExemploDoLivroDeSpringBootFB). 

Comment: alterei a resposta com todas modificações minimas, no mais considero dar uma relida no conteúdo de spring, principalmente quanto a questão do mapeamento, se der tudo certo por gentileza marca como correto :D

Comment: Ok. Mas dá uma olhada no [repositório do livro](https://github.com/boaglio/spring-boot-greendogdelivery-casadocodigo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/boaglio/casadocodigo/greendogdelivery/controller/ClienteController.java). Parece funcionar. Agora a view funcionou aqui, mas ainda não consigo acessar `list` que deveria permitir acessar todos os registros existentes no banco.

Comment: observe que na pasta template do seu exemplo existe uma pasta chamada clientes:
https://github.com/boaglio/spring-boot-greendogdelivery-casadocodigo/tree/master/src/main/resources/templates

Comment: na sua você não tem, então se você tenta mapear clientes/list ele não encontra, porque não existe o caminho

Comment: Fiz a correções e [subi no GitHub](https://github.com/vanribeiro/ExemploDoLivroDeSpringBootFB/blob/master/src/main/java/com/greendog/controladores/ClienteController.java). As rotas funcionam. Perdão, realmente não tinha observado essa questão do diretório `clientes`. Mas ainda não consigo encontrar o `form`. Quando tento acessar a rota: `http://localhost:8080/clientes/novo`, recebo esse erro: `An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/clientes/form.html]")`.

Comment: Já resolvi o problema do `parsing`. Muito obrigada! ^_^

Comment: de nada, desculpa a demora, qualquer coisa estamos aí

Comment: Que isso, imagina! Eu que agradeço!